# Java output formatting -- trailing zeros

Tags: java, output

I have a few doubles in my code that need to output with no more than two decimal places while ignoring trailing zeros.  For example:

```
    2.0334=2.03  
    10.20=10.2  
    24.0032=24
```

I also have other doubles that I have to output with different formats, including trailing zeros and different precisions.  Multiple formats may be output in the same System.out.format() line.  From what I know about DecimalFormat (which, admittedly, isn't much), I can't output two decimals with different formats on the same line.  I'm trying to use System.out.format() for that reason, but I can't make it ignore trailing zeros.  Is this possible, or am I stuck with only DecimalFormat?  Thanks!

Comment: You can output two numbers with different formats on the same line using multiple instances of DecimalFormat.  If that's what you want to do.  You just can't use the same instance to format in two different ways at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different instances of `DecimalFormat` to format various numbers as you wish first and print them afterwards.

```
double num1 = 2.0334;  
double num2 = 10.2;
double num3 = 24.0032;

DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
DecimalFormat df3 = new DecimalFormat("#");

System.out.print(String.format("%s %s %s", df1.format(num1), df2.format(num2),
        df3.format(num3));
```

Or straight away using formatted output of `printf()`,

```
System.out.printf("%.2f %.1f, %.0f", num1, num2, num3);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, wasn't aware I could do that.  But for my own curiosity, is there any way to do it without DecimalFormat?  For example (with made up syntax): System.out.format("%.2f, %.3f", double1(ignoreZeros), double2) ?

Comment: Yup you can, and you almost nailed the syntax too, check System.out.prinf() documentation for details.

Comment: I'm looking through the documentation, but I don't see any way to remove trailing zeros from a double.  Leading zeros, yes, but not trailing zeros.  Any way you'd be willing to show me the syntax you're talking about?  Thanks!

Comment: If you want to remove trailing zeroes, I'd say you have to stick to DecimalFormat(), or do it manually, no way of doing it through formatted string output I know of.